# Can Not Set Border on UIView

Tags: ios, uiview

I am having a problem setting the border colour on a UIView.  If set `tempColor` to `[UIColor lighGreyColor], [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0],` or `[UIColor blueColor]`, the border gets set as expected. However, the code below does not set the colour and no border appears.  `unamecontainer` is `UIView`. Any ideas why I can set the border colour to the colours mentioned above, and not the to the colour below.

```
UIColor *tempColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:169 green:201 blue:229 alpha:1.0];
self.unamecontainer.layer.borderColor = tempColor.CGColor;
self.unamecontainer.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RGB values for `UIColor` need to be in the range `[0, 1]`, so you need to divide each value by `255.0` (not `255` because that is integer division) to get a percentage:

```
UIColor *tempColor = [[UIColor alloc]
    initWithRed: 169/255.0
    green:       201/255.0
    blue:        229/255.0
    alpha:       1.0];
```

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. But, why does `[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:255 gree:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0]` work?

Comment: By an educated guess, the implementation of `UIColor` (which is a wrapper for `CGColor`) sees the 255 as >1, so it treats it as 1. If (255, 0, 0) is red, (2, 0, 0) will also be red.

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
yourView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:204.0f/255.0f green:204.0f/255.0f   blue:204.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
view_buttons.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
```

Comment: Good answers accompany code samples with an explanation for future readers. While the person asking this question may understand your answer, explaining how you arrived at it will help countless others.

Answer (score 0):

red, green, and blue are floats from 0 to 1.
Try

```
UIColor *tempColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:(169/255)f green:(201/255)f blue:(229/255)f alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: Bit out of date, but `(169/255)f` will do an int division, which will give 0, then convert to float. This will always set the color as black.